# Printing HTML string

Tags: html, asp.net, printing, string-formatting, streamreader

I have a string with HTML tags which renders on page perfectly with correct formatting. Now I want to PRINT same string containing HTML tags on A4 sheet with proper formatting as I see on HTMl Page, but after printing (using StreamReader object) Printed page shows string as it is without any formatting.
Please help me to complete my task as I want to print a string(containing HTML tags) with prper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

> You must write all the css code inside the tag. Then that is print correct format.

Comment: Example of my String :

<html><body><table width=15% border=0 style='font-family:Arial; font-size:10px;'><tr><td colspan='3' width=100%>1 - Dabuscos</td></tr><tr><td> Order No</td><td width=5%>:</td><td> 190</td></tr><tr><td> Order Date</td><td>:</td><td> 06 Sep 2013, 1:09 AM</td></table>
</html></body>

Comment: All the values must with in the double quates